# IE breaking navigation menu with search

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a standard NAV menu created with UL and LI elements. Now on Chrome, Firefox and the newer/newest version of Internet Explorer it all looks fine, but try IE7 (and probably 8) and the search on the right drops down below the home button. While I know my code works for all the latest versions of browsers, I don't know what CSS to give my navigation menu to fix this, if the user is using an older version.

I've included the HTML and CSS below and a screenshot of the correct style, conditional statements I know about, but the actual appropriate code to get my navigation to style properly for older versions of IE is what I'm after.

Live URL - http://bit.ly/1gC4JiA

*UPDATE* This is what my client see's (he's using bloody IE8 and won't update):
[image]

```
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
        </li>
                                    <li>
                <a href="#">Felt Bags</a>
                    </li>
                                    <li>
                <a href="#">Felt Accessories</a>
                    </li>
                                    <li>
                <a href="#">Canvas Collection</a>
                    </li>
                                    <li>
                <a href="#">Gadget Carriers</a>
                    </li>
                                    <li>
                <a href="#">Laptop Backpacks</a>
                    </li>
                                    <li>
                <a href="#">Travel Bags</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" name="search" class="header-search" style="width: 120px;">
            <span class="button-search"></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
    /* Navigation Menu */

nav {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 990px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    background: #929292; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%, #383838 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#929292), color-stop(99%,#383838)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#929292', endColorstr='#383838',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    padding: 10px 8px 10px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right: 1px solid #343434;
    border-left: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
}

nav ul li:hover, nav ul li.active {
    display: inline;
    background: #383838; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #383838 1%, #929292 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#383838), color-stop(100%,#929292)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #383838 1%,#929292 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #383838 1%,#929292 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #383838 1%,#929292 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #383838 1%,#929292 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#383838', endColorstr='#929292',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    padding: 10px 8px 10px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #929292; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%, #383838 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#929292), color-stop(99%,#383838)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#929292', endColorstr='#383838',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    padding: 10px 11px 10px 11px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-right: 1px solid #343434;
    border-left: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-right: none;
    padding-right: 85px;
    padding-left:72px;
    background: #929292; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%, #383838 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#929292), color-stop(99%,#383838)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #929292 0%,#383838 99%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#929292', endColorstr='#383838',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
nav ul li a,nav ul li a:hover,nav ul li a:active,nav ul li a:visited{color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}
nav ul li i {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: It's not the background gradient I need help with, it's the position of the search bar/last element of the nav. I'll update this post with a screenshot.

Comment: hope you are charging them more for using a 5 year old browser :) IE 11 is a free upgrade. #justsaying

Comment: I told the client time and time again to update and he's just saying "But what if my visitors also use IE8?". The bloody shoot them! lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to IE8

```
nav {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 990px;
  display: table\9; // add this
  margin-bottom: 5px\9; // add this
  // Hack to IE8 (using \9)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dispaly your `nav` element as a block level element, since as you know, the element does not exists in IE and when it is created by javascript, by default it is displayed as inline level element

```
nav {

   display:block;

   font-size: 1.3em;
   margin-top: 40px;
   width: 990px;
}
```

And, do not forget, create the `nav` element for IE ´8 and lower.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script>
    document.createElement("nav");
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```